# How can I call the "net share" command from within my program?

Tags: c#, winforms, process

I am currently trying to make an application that uses the command `net share` from the CMD. However, when I press on the button that runs the code, it gives me the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "net share";
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = txt_shareName + "=" + path;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.Start();
txt_Logs.Text = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

But when you put `ipconfig` into the FileName part and `/all` into the Arguments part, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `StartInfo.File`, "net share" is not a valid filename.

Try this

```
Process cmd = new Process()'
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "net";
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "share " + txt_shareName + "=" + path;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.Start();
```

If the `path` contain spaces, you will need to quote it.

Answer (score 0):

"net" it's a programm and "share" argument. Try this:

```
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "net";
cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "share " + txt_shareName + "=" + path;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process cmd = new Process();
            cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "net";
            cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "share";
            cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmd.Start();
```

net is a exe in sys32.. share is an argument.. add it to your aguments..

Answer (score 0):

It is because `net share` requires Administrative privilege to run this command.
When you try to run only `Net Share` it will perfectly and it doesn't require any special privilege. But when you try run the command with parameters in the command prompt it will give error stating

> System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.

So you need to run as administrator

The possible solution might be that you could run the Visual Studio as administrator

To run the command with [administrator privilege](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) whereas if the OS is Vista or higher you can do it like below

```
if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
{
   p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Mohit, this is a problem of admin rights. You can run process as administrator from C# by adding following:

```
cmd.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```